# Downloading design step attachments from HP ALM

Tags: c#, hp-alm

I was using below code to download attachments for test cases at the `HP ALM TestLab` folder,
But then I find out that attachments can be available at the step level too.
So is there any way to download  attachments for test steps?

I tried with changing 2nd line to

```
TDAPIOLELib.StepFactory tsTestFact = tDConnection.StepFactory;
```

But it was not working.

```
public void DownloadTestAttachments_FromVB_TestLab()

        {

            String AttachmentDownloadPath = @"C:\temp";

            TDAPIOLELib.TSTestFactory tsTestFact = tDConnection.TSTestFactory;

            TDAPIOLELib.List tsTestList = tsTestFact.NewList("");

            TDAPIOLELib.AttachmentFactory attFact;

            TDAPIOLELib.List attList;

            Console.WriteLine("Downloading attachments for the Tests : " + AttachmentDownloadPath);

            try

            {

                foreach (TDAPIOLELib.TSTest tsItem in tsTestList)

                {

                    if (tsItem.HasAttachment == true)

                    {

                        attFact = tsItem.Attachments;

                        attList = attFact.NewList("");

                        foreach (TDAPIOLELib.Attachment attItem in attList)

                        {

                            attItem.Load(true, AttachmentDownloadPath + "\\" + attItem.Name);

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            catch (Exception x)

            {

                Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());

            }

        }
```